# Solaris 10: How do I get to the {ok} prompt from here?

Tags: solaris-10, sparc

My Sparc box which is running Solaris 10 stopped working due (I think) to a power outage. Now I can't get it to boot up. I'm not interested in trying to recover the contents of the hard-disk. I just want to make the machine usable again. So I am trying to install the OS from the CD Rom drives. I have removed the hard drives so that it doesn't try to boot off them

This is what I see on the serial connection:

```
INIT: create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
create: Permission denied
INIT: 
-> 

-> n
Invalid command 'n' - type help for a list of commands.

-> help
The help command is used to view information about commands and targets

Usage: help [-o|-output terse|verbose] [<command>|legal|targets|<target>|<target> <property>]

Special characters used in the help command are
[]   encloses optional keywords or options
<>   encloses a description of the keyword
     (If <> is not present, an actual keyword is indicated)
|    indicates a choice of keywords or options

help <target>              displays description if this target and its properties
help <target> <property>   displays description of this property of this target
help targets               displays a list of targets
help legal                 displays the product legal notice

Commands are:
cd
create
delete
dump
exit
help
load
reset
set
show
start
stop
version
```

What I need to know is how do I get to the {Ok} prompt from here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either be on the RSC interface (if your box has one) or on the console via keyboard/monitor to where you can see the initial POST sequence.  Then you'll need to issue a break command before it gets to the default boot choice.

However, your end prompt looks almost like an > prompt.  Try typing `n` there to see if it takes you to the OK prompt.

Comment: I made some edits to my original post showing that "n" doesn't work, but also showing the menu that is available to me.

Comment: Control-break should do it. Either hit ctrl-break on your keyboard or find the send break command for your terminal emulator.